# Converting ActiveDs.LargeInteger to Long in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I'm trying to compute the password expiry date, and most of the example code is in C#

One sample has:

```
IADsLargeInteger largeInt;
largeInt = (IADsLargeInteger) largeIntVal;   
myLong = (long)largeInt.HighPart << 32 | (uint)largeInt.LowPart;
```

If I try something similar in VB.net:

```
dim myLong as Long
myLong = largeInt.HighPart << 32 Or largeInt.LowPart
```

Then I seem to get an invalid value.  How can I obtain similar results in VB?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706037) the problem is because VB.Net has no unsigned integer class.

The solution is:

```
props = resultDE.Properties("pwdLastSet")
Dim prop As ActiveDs.LargeInteger
prop = props(0)

Dim int64Value As Long
Dim strTemp As String
strTemp = "&H" + CStr(Hex(prop.HighPart)) + CStr(Hex(prop.LowPart))
int64Value = Val(strTemp)
```